# Javascript function passed as parameter not executing

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, parameter-passing, execute

I have an App.jsx, declaring a constant and setState routine.  I put the setState in a function (update_word_list).  I pass the function down to a sub-component.  A console.log prints the typeof parameter as 'function' and a print of the function itself shows that the function is interpreted in the sub-component.  **The function does not execute.**

I am new to Javascript.  I apologise if I'm doing something dumb (needless to say...).

A lot of Code below, so I hope this describes localisation of issue in WordsSample.jsx.  Overview/summary actions:
**App.jsx**:

1. Declare variable and setState:  const [word_list, setWord_List] = useState(["1", "2"])
2. Define function containing setState (note: console.log as first statement):
   `function **Update_Word_List** (word_list)  { console.log("Update word list inside app.js  + word_list") setWord_List(word_list={word_list}) return (word_list) }`
3. Pass anonymised function to sub component:  <WordSample word_list={word_list} dowords={()=>Update_Word_List}/>

**WordsSample.jsx**

1. Pass props through to SendSample function onClick:  <button type="submit" onClick={()=>SendSample(props)} name="genwords" id="genword">Names
2. Receive props into SendSample, console.log typeof (recognised as function), and function (recognised as function invocation ??):

```
function SendSample( props ) {
    console.log("Props value: " + typeof(props.dowords))
    console.log("Props value: " + props.dowords)
```

3. **The problem!!!** Try to execute the function:  props.dowords(strwords).
4. Localisation: console.log after the function should have executed:  console.log("In theory we have done the function" + props.word_list)
   Notes:

- The function should have changed the initial props.word_list value,which is unchanged.
- The function invocation is after return from an axios.post.  The axios.post has worked, and provided a 200 http return, and I have console.logged to ensure that data has been returned.
- 

[Console log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUdpj.png)

Surrounding Code:

```
import './App.css';
import ControlS from './Controls'
import WordSample from './WordsSample'
import List_Words from './List_Words';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


function App() {

  const [word_list, setWord_List] = useState(["1", "2"])

  function update_word_list (word_list)  {
    console.log("Update word list inside app.js  + word_list")
    setWord_List(word_list={word_list})
    return (word_list)
  }


  useEffect (() => {
    <App />
  }, []);
  

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ControlS />
      <WordSample word_list={word_list} dowords={()=>update_word_list}/>
      <List_Words word_list={word_list}/>
```

Word_Sample sub component.  Notes:
Button in Word_sample invoking function sendSample with props.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import endPoints from './api';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function WordSample(props) {

    let [sample, setWordSample] =  useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        loadSample()
    }, [])

const loadSample = async () => {
    const data = await endPoints.sample();
    setWordSample(sample=data)
}


function sendSample( props ) {
    console.log("Props value: " + props.dowords)

    let send = {}
    send['words'] =  sample

    axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*";

    axios.post('/genwords', send, {
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         }
       }).then(res => {
            // console.log("Response words:" + JSON.stringify(res.data))
            let strwords = JSON.stringify(res.data)
            strwords = strwords.split(",")
            props.dowords(strwords)
            console.log("In theory we have done the function" + props.word_list)

            // word_list.forEach((word, i)=>console.log(word))
       }).catch(err=>console.log("Error found:  " + err))

       return(
        <>
        <h2>Literal</h2>

        </>
       )

    }
    

    return (
        <div className="wordsample">
            
                <div className="ctlheader">
                    <h1>Word Sample</h1>
                </div>
                <p>Type (or paste) the word sample that you would like to generate sci-fi names from</p>
            <form id="form" method="POST">
                <textarea placeholder={sample} id="word" name="words" required
                onChange={(e)=>setWordSample(sample=e.target.value)}></textarea>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" onClick={()=>sendSample(props)} name="genwords" id="genword">Names</button>
            </form>                  
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `dowords={()=>update_word_list}` ... so, `dowords` is a function that returns the function `update_word_list` - it doesn't run it, just returns it? perhaps you meant `dowords={(...args)=>update_word_list(...args)}`?

Comment: Thank you for quick response!!  I don't quite understand (so sorry!!).  What I'm trying to do is run update_word_list from a sub function.  The sub function provides the data/args required to run update_word_list.  So I want:  (1) dowords=function, as you say.  (2) run the function, having returned its "definition" from a sub function.  I won't know (...args) when I define dowords.  Thanks again!!  Sorry if I'm garbling...

Comment: did you try it? see, I was going to suggest `dowords={update_word_list}` but I don't do reactjs so no idea if that would work - but basically `dowords={(...args)=>update_word_list(...args)}` is the same functionality ... you set dwords to be a function that calls another function, passing in all the `...args` ... - you could have `...pineapples` in place of the `...args` ... `args` is just a parameter name, so what you call it is irrelevant

Comment: I did try a few variations on the theme of your ideas.  I'm still missing how to execute the update_word_list function.  I agree that I seem to be passing a 'pointer' to it, rather than the executable function.  Thanks again for your inputs, but not quite there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

I've cracked this - not entirely to my satisfaction.  Very simply, I pass the setState function directly:

I guess I'm confused about:

1. Why so much documentation suggests this is a bad idea (which makes me uncomfortable that it still is!!!).
2. Why this is different to passing any other function as a parameter...

So still some mystery.  I'll update if I bottom it out.  For now: with thanks for the kind help, I don't want anyone else spending time on this.  Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x in particular!!